# Traveling to Northern Kosovo (e.g. Zubin Potok)

Tags: borders, permits, kosovo

We are three guys traveling to Kosovo for a road trip. We would like to visit the northern part of Kosovo (e.g. northern part of Mitrovica, Zubin Potok). However, authorities from our homeland advise against going there. And our car rental agency forbids us from taking a car there as well.

- What options do we have? Can we go there by bus / foot? Can we organize a guided tour?
- How safe is it today?
- Can we potentially have troubles crossing the “bridge border” in Mitrovica?

Comment: The question is a bit odd. The reason you cannot take the rental car is probably because their insurance does not cover Kosovo. There are obvious options like buses. The only issue (I think) is that you cannot cross from Kosovo into Serbia if you did not enter Kosovo from Serbia first.

Comment: @TomasBy it is fine that we cannot take the car there. We are wondering if there are possibilities to take a cab for a guided tour. And also we are worried about safety.

Comment: @TomasBy Unless using an EU/Schengen/Yugoslav national ID card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just been there.

> What options do we have? Can we go there by bus / foot? Can we
>   organize a guided tour?

There are no issue crossing the "border" between Kosovo and northern Kosovo. In fact, there is no "border". There are some [KFOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosovo_Force) police, but in fact much smaller presence, than in some regions (e.g. Prizren). There are absolutely no issues crossing it by foot, no documents are checked. Organized tours are definitely possible, but one has to find a guide.

> How safe is it today?

It feels safe, it looks safe. We have not seen any Kosovo / Serbia related issues. There are tons of Serbian flags, attributes, etc once you cross the bridge in Mitrovica. However, one has to be aware about incidents like [this](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/16/world/europe/kosovo-serb-oliver-ivanovic-killed.html) which probably explains why authorities do not recommend going to Northern Kosovo.

> Can we potentially have troubles crossing the “bridge border” in
>   Mitrovica?

As mentioned above there are absolutely no issues crossing the bridge.